# How can play sound in background mode on IOS 13 SDK with cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I have compiled an IOS app that play some sounds.
For this I have used the plugin "cordova-plugin-background-mode".

When I have compiled with IOS SDK 11 the sound runs when the app is minimized or the phone is suspended.
When I have compiled with the IOS SDK 13 the sound does not play minimized or suspended.

Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thank you very much for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used the </audio/> html element controlled by Javascript for my Phonegap / Cordova project and works minimized or suspended.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio